# Mate compositing windows manager

Tags: 14.04, mate, compositing

I have a little problem. I've installed mate on my ubuntu 14.04 and now I need to install the compositing windows manager to run docky. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

first ensure you have installed compiz:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins compizconfig-settings-manager
```

open compiz settings manager by typing `ccsm` in the terminal, or just find it in the dash.

Under EFFECTS, enable Window Decorations.

This is where I got stuck for 2 months. In most distros, this is all you have to do, but there is another step in Mate:

Open a terminal and type:

```
dconf write /org/mate/marco/general/compositing-manager true
```

You should now have compositing enabled.